# c# mvc 2 - map a catchall route for all images

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to make a route to catch all image requests via regex, and use a image http handler.

I've tried adding regex's (as with routes.IgnoreRoute), however, I receive errors about the url parameter for routing.

I have also tried the following to try and catch bitmap images, although nothing is caught:

routes.Add("ImagesBMPRoute", new Route("{filename}.bmp/{*pathInfo}", new ImageRouteHandler()));

Can anyone advise how I can catch all "bmp" extension requests and pass to the ImageRouteHandler

Thank you,

Frank

Answer (score 2):

Static files are directly served to clients,be sure that web.config file includes

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Take a look this post [ASP.Net MVC – How to route to images or other file types](http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I need requests for the images to be routed through the ImageRouteHandler class, as they are located in a different area to the path sent to the browser.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I just add a link, i hope you found usefull